# What are these files ,can I delete them manually?

Tags: mysql, log-files

```
[root@jiaoyou mysql]# pwd
/var/lib/mysql
[root@jiaoyou mysql]# ls -ls
338256 -rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 346030080 2010-04-22 08:08 ibdata1
626812 -rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 641222072 2010-01-26 07:17 mysql-bin.000008
316892 -rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 324173772 2010-03-25 12:51 mysql-bin.000009
52724 -rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql  53931666 2010-04-12 12:13 mysql-bin.000010
10136 -rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql  10359639 2010-04-22 08:32 mysql-bin.000011

mysql> SHOW BINARY LOGS; 
+------------------+-----------+
| Log_name         | File_size |
+------------------+-----------+
| mysql-bin.000008 | 641222072 | 
| mysql-bin.000009 | 324173772 | 
| mysql-bin.000010 |  53931666 | 
| mysql-bin.000011 |  10360680 | 
+------------------+-----------+
```

These files `ibdata1`,`mysql-bin.000008` and `mysql-bin.000009` ... are taking up too much of my space,will it be ok for me to delete some of them manually?

**UPDATE**
I'm not utilizing MySQL's master/slave,how to drop and disable all the binary files?

Comment: SHOW BINARY LOGS; may return an error message like "Error 1381: You are not using binary logging".

Comment: If you do receive the Error 1381: You are not using binary logging message, what does that mean? Is it then safe to manually delete the files?

Answer (score 13):

Those are mysql bin logs.  The server can get seriously irritated if you delete them with rm.

Instead, use `PURGE BINARY LOGS TO 'mysql-bin.010';` as the root mysql user to let it safely delete the files.

More information can be found [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/purge-binary-logs.html) in the documentation.

Comment: What's the relation between these BINARY LOGS?

Comment: These are the files that are in your database /var/lib/mysql directory.

Answer (score 7):

These are the logs files for mysql service. The setting can be customized by updating /etc/my.cnf file

If they are eating up your disk space then add the setting to auto clear logs based on number of days you want to keep

For e.g. below setting will delete all logs older than 90 days

```
**expire_logs_days=100**
```

to reflect this setting we need to restart the mysql service

```
/etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This is the most durable solution. Also the easiest way to purge if you don't quite remember your MySQL passwords :-)

Comment: Best solution ever! If you want to purge all files, just set to 0 days, and then back to a good value based on your application.

Thanks, pal!

Comment: Use binlog_expire_logs_seconds to set the expire time (expire_logs_days is deprecated)
mysql> SET GLOBAL binlog_expire_logs_seconds = 604800;

Comment: my.cnf file was in /etc/mysql/my.cnf

Answer (score 5):

The `mysql-bin` files are the binary logs, which are typically both for either a transaction history or for the purpose of replication.  To disable binary logging, you can comment the `log-bin*` lines in the cnf.  `log-slave-updates` should be commented too if enabled.

`ibdata*` files are part of InnoDB's tablespace, which is specified with the `innodb_data_file_path` setting.  I wouldn't recommend deleting unless you have no InnoDB tables and first disable InnoDB by using `skip-innodb` in the cnf.

Comment: Do I need to comment the `server-id` to disable it?

Comment: No, you do not but you could.  That is used for identifying the server uniquely during replication.

Answer (score 1):

To disable the logging entirely you need to comment out the log-bin value in your config file (typically /etc/my.cnf):

```
#log-bin = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
```

I think the ibdata1 file might contain the actual database though - I don't use innodb so I'm not sure - and so I would not recommend removing that one.  The "PURGE BINARY LOGS TO..." command will get rid of the binary logs though.